# What is the best VOIP toolset for use with .Net development?

Tags: asp.net, windows, voip

I have a need to explore VOIP integration into a .Net application. It would be incredibly helpful if the toolset was usable via ASP.Net (version 2.0 or higher), and provided the developer the option to allow interaction on the client either embedded within the web browser or external to the client web browser. It should be compatible at a minimum with Internet Explorer, but would be better if browser independence were an option.

Comment: What are you looking to do with VOIP?

Comment: This would be for enabling voice communication and dialing capabilities within web applications. I'm aware of using Skype, but am curious of any other alternatives that would potentially allow hosting in a ASP.Net web form, or perhaps Silverlight.

Comment: There are Flash-based softphones. I'd use that, then you can use Flash's XML socket support to communicate with a server for call control. I don't think SL supports microphones. ActiveX is another possible option.

Comment: I'm curious to also look into the details concering Microsoft's Communication Server and any development interfaces that it may expose.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question -- what are you trying to DO with VoIP? Since you mentioned ASP.NET I'm guessing you mean some kind of server app? If you explain more about what you want to do, we can give you better advice.

You could check out Microsoft's Speech stuff: http://www.microsoft.com/speech/speech2007/default.mspx. As I understand it, Speech Server was moved into being part of OCS. I remember that it supported using .NET 3.0's Workflow Foundation as well as some multi-modal stuff with ASP.NET.

[FreeSWITCH](http://www.freeswitch.org) is a flexible VoIP system that works for both large-scale server implementations as well as embedded scenarios (say as an ActiveX softphone). There is full .NET and Mono support via [mod_managed](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_managed). (This allows you to create voice applications in FreeSWITCH using any .NET language.) There's also an XML-based API that allows you to send and receive events to control a remote FS server. You could use this from ASP.NET. FreeSWITCH is very active in #freeswitch@irc.freenode.net so you can get a lot of advice there.